# Woocommerce Product Quantity Filter Slider - Widget

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, widget

I am trying to add a widget to Woocommerce to Filter Products by  Quantity with a slider. I got this far by changing the open source code of woocommerce for the price filter slider. It print no errors once it's on the website but it does not filter the results. The output on the URL is also as expected. The slider does not work but it's fine if I cannot fix it. As of now it has two type-in fields: max and min stock quantity. Please help. I am sure others will benefit from this. I need it because the website is for wholesale and if a product is not available is a min quantity that a client wants, they can filter it out.

```
   // Register and load the widget
function my_stock_widget() {
    register_widget( 'WC_Widget_Stock_Filter' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_stock_widget' );

class WC_Widget_Stock_Filter extends WC_Widget {
    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->widget_cssclass    = 'woocommerce widget_stock_filter';
        $this->widget_description = __( 'Shows a stock filter slider in a widget which lets you narrow down the list of shown products when viewing product categories.', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->widget_id          = 'woocommerce_stock_filter';
        $this->widget_name        = __( 'WooCommerce stock filter', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->settings           = array(
            'title'  => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'std'   => __( 'Filter by stock', 'woocommerce' ),
                'label' => __( 'Title', 'woocommerce' ),
            ),
        );
        $suffix = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
        wp_register_script( 'accounting', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/accounting/accounting' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), '0.4.2' );
        wp_register_script( 'wc-jquery-ui-touchpunch', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery-ui-touch-punch' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery-ui-slider' ), WC_VERSION, true );
        wp_register_script( 'wc-stock-slider', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/frontend/price-slider' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery-ui-slider', 'wc-jquery-ui-touchpunch', 'accounting' ), WC_VERSION, true );
        wp_localize_script( 'wc-stock-slider', 'woocommerce_stock_slider_params', array(
            'min_stock'                    => isset( $_GET['min_stock'] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['min_stock'] ) : '',
            'max_stock'                    => isset( $_GET['max_stock'] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['max_stock'] ) : '',
            'currency_format_num_decimals' => 0,
//          'currency_format_symbol'       => get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(),
            'currency_format_decimal_sep'  => esc_attr( wc_get_price_decimal_separator() ),
            'currency_format_thousand_sep' => esc_attr( wc_get_price_thousand_separator() ),
//          'currency_format'              => esc_attr( str_replace( array( '%1$s', '%2$s' ), array( '%s', '%v' ), get_woocommerce_stock_format() ) ),
        ) );
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * Output widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget
     *
     * @param array $args
     * @param array $instance
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        global $wp, $wp_the_query;
        if ( ! is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && ! is_tax( get_object_taxonomies( 'product' ) ) ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( ! $wp_the_query->post_count ) {
            return;
        }
        $min_stock = isset( $_GET['min_stock'] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['min_stock'] ) : '';
        $max_stock = isset( $_GET['max_stock'] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['max_stock'] ) : '';
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-stock-slider' );
        // Find min and max stock in current result set
        $stocks = $this->get_filtered_stock();
        $min    = floor( $stocks->min_stock );
        $max    = ceil( $stocks->max_stock );
        if ( $min === $max ) {
            return;
        }
        $this->widget_start( $args, $instance );
        if ( '' === get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {
            $form_action = remove_query_arg( array( 'page', 'paged' ), add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) ) );
        } else {
            $form_action = preg_replace( '%\/page/[0-9]+%', '', home_url( trailingslashit( $wp->request ) ) );
        }
        /**
         * Adjust max if the store taxes are not displayed how they are stored.
         * Min is left alone because the product may not be taxable.
         * Kicks in when stocks excluding tax are displayed including tax.
         *
        if ( wc_tax_enabled() && 'incl' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_shop' ) && ! wc_stocks_include_tax() ) {
            $tax_classes = array_merge( array( '' ), WC_Tax::get_tax_classes() );
            $class_max   = $max;
            foreach ( $tax_classes as $tax_class ) {
                if ( $tax_rates = WC_Tax::get_rates( $tax_class ) ) {
                    $class_max = $max + WC_Tax::get_tax_total( WC_Tax::calc_exclusive_tax( $max, $tax_rates ) );
                }
            }
            $max = $class_max;
        }*/
        echo '<form method="get" action="' . esc_url( $form_action ) . '">
            <div class="stock_slider_wrapper">
                <div class="stock_slider" style="display:none;"></div>
                <div class="stock_slider_amount">
                    <input type="text" id="min_stock" name="min_stock" value="' . esc_attr( $min_stock ) . '" data-min="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_filter_widget_min_amount', $min ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Min stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
                    <input type="text" id="max_stock" name="max_stock" value="' . esc_attr( $max_stock ) . '" data-max="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_filter_widget_max_amount', $max ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Max stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
                    <button type="submit" class="button">' . esc_html__( 'Filter', 'woocommerce' ) . '</button>
                    <div class="stock_label" style="display:none;">
                        ' . esc_html__( 'Stock:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="from"></span> &mdash; <span class="to"></span>
                    </div>
                    ' . wc_query_string_form_fields( null, array( 'min_stock', 'max_stock' ), '', true ) . '
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>';
        $this->widget_end( $args );
    }
    /**
     * Get filtered min stock for current products.
     * @return int
     */
    protected function get_filtered_stock() {
        global $wpdb, $wp_the_query;
        $args       = $wp_the_query->query_vars;
        $tax_query  = isset( $args['tax_query'] ) ? $args['tax_query'] : array();
        $meta_query = isset( $args['meta_query'] ) ? $args['meta_query'] : array();
        if ( ! is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && ! empty( $args['taxonomy'] ) && ! empty( $args['term'] ) ) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => $args['taxonomy'],
                'terms'    => array( $args['term'] ),
                'field'    => 'slug',
            );
        }
        foreach ( $meta_query + $tax_query as $key => $query ) {
            if ( ! empty( $query['stock_filter'] ) || ! empty( $query['rating_filter'] ) ) {
                unset( $meta_query[ $key ] );
            }
        }
        $meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query );
        $tax_query  = new WP_Tax_Query( $tax_query );
        $meta_query_sql = $meta_query->get_sql( 'post', $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );
        $tax_query_sql  = $tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );
        $sql  = "SELECT min( FLOOR( stock_meta.meta_value ) ) as min_stock, max( CEILING( stock_meta.meta_value ) ) as max_stock FROM {$wpdb->posts} ";
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} as stock_meta ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = stock_meta.post_id " . $tax_query_sql['join'] . $meta_query_sql['join'];
        $sql .= "   WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type IN ('" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_filter_meta_keys', array( 'product' ) ) ) ) . "')
                    AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish'
                    AND stock_meta.meta_key IN ('" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_filter_meta_keys', array( '_stock' ) ) ) ) . "')
                    AND stock_meta.meta_value > '' ";
        $sql .= $tax_query_sql['where'] . $meta_query_sql['where'];
        if ( $search = WC_Query::get_main_search_query_sql() ) {
            $sql .= ' AND ' . $search;
        }
        return $wpdb->get_row( $sql );
    }
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I could use this also.

Comment: Not really. Still looking for help with this